# iPhone SDK: resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: iphone

For some reason, resignFirstResponder is not working. I am not sure why? I have tried to call it from textFieldDidEndEditing and nothing happens. A NIB is being used and each's delegate is pointing to files owner.

What needs to be done to get the keyboard to dismiss?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
} @interface MultiSalesViewController : ScrollingViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `-textFieldDidEndEditing`. That's called after the text field resigns firstResponder status, which is what you're trying to use it as a hook to make happen. Cart before horse, chicken-and-egg kind of problem.

Instead use `-textFieldShouldReturn` to get triggered when the return key is pressed (and remember to `return YES;` from that.) Also float a clear custom button behind the elements of the view and handle a "background tap" that goes through all the text fields on your view and resigns first responder on the lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

actually you should return NO so that the text field does not begin editing at all. If it does, the firstresponder gets set and the keyboard pops up again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your setting your delegates for the textfield.

```
myTextField.delegTe = self;
```

And you are using in your header:

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**EDIT:**

Try:

```
if(textField == myTextField){
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: The delegate has been already been set both in IB and in viewDidLoad. And the view controller already adopts the UITextFieldDelegate. Still, the keyboard is not dismissing.